# Storing project gloal forms/classes in C#

Tags: c#, forms, global

I am working on a 20 year old program that was written by multiple programmers that apparently didn't know that comments exist (also the code is in german).

In the project there are multiple forms and classes that are global for all projects in the solution (for example choose project, choose file, enter name...)

Right now these forms are stored in whatever project programmer had open at the time which makes it really annoying to find anything.

How would you go about storing forms that are global to all of the projects of the solution (can be opened and used by any project)? Would you create a new project that would store them? Are there some better ways to do it in Visual Studio? How would you handle storing global forms/classes in general?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Id probably put them at least in a similar folder structure in each project where they are created.  But really, if you have a decent IDE then you shouldn't have too much problem finding them using the goto symbol / anything functionality

Comment: *"these forms are stored in whatever"* - I doubt it. There is probably a logic in placing forms and it's totally fine to have difficulties to find things in someone else project. Get familiar with it, ask questions to other programmers of it, use "Find all references", "Go to definition" and solution explorer "Sync with active document", those reduce the need of knowing where is what significantly. P.S.: I am the author of 15 years old program.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal approach would be separating reusable code from non-reusable code as well as platform dependent and platform independent code. This will require you to create another project that would be shared among your other projects within the same solution.

I.E.

Shared:

- Foo - Reusable Class Library/Portable Class Library (PCL) (Platform Independent)
- Bar - Reusable Forms Project (Platform Dependent)

---

Main:

- Forms Project A uses Bar
- Forms Project B uses Foo & Bar
- Web Project C uses Foo (Cannot use Bar because of platform incompatibility)

---

Business logic that are platform independent are ideally written in a separate project so that multiple platforms could reuse the code.

Note that Forms projects and Web Projects are 2 different platforms and cannot mutually share codes.